# Ignoring buffer files in processing

Tags: r, las, lidr

I'm wondering if it is possible to include some `las` files in a `LAScatalog` only for the purpose of providing a buffer to other `las` files.

For example, I may only want to normalize 2 `las` files and use buffer zones of neighbouring files to avoid edge artefacts, but never fully process the neighbouring files.

I don't think `lasclip()` will do what I want since `lasclip()` essentially creates a single `las` file from a region of interest.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Update**

No, it is not possible yet with current release (v2.1.4). However this feature has been added in v2.2.0 that will be release in January 2020 but available on github. In v2.2.0 you can add a column `processed` that contains booleans in the `LAScatalog` to tell the engine that some of the files must not be processed

```
ctg$processed <- TRUE
ctg$processed[3:9] <- FALSE
```

The files flagged `FALSE` are not removed from the `LAScatalog` but they are not processed. They are however used to load a buffer in processed files.

The `plot()` function shows which file are actually processed. And the `catalog_select()` function allows for interactive flagging.

[image]

More details [here](https://github.com/Jean-Romain/lidR/issues/298).

---

**Old answer**

No, it is not possible yet. However this is a fair feature request and I opened a request on the [lidR repository](https://github.com/Jean-Romain/lidR/issues/298).

It is also correct that `lasclip` won't help you here. Actually the problem is more complex than it appears and I can't even see a partial workaround with existing tools. But such option will be added internally as soon as possible and this answer will be edited later to reflect how this new feature can be used.